# Jenkins fails when compiling .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, jenkins, xib

I am building an iPad app with Jenkins and it consistently fails when compiling a single .xib. The app compiles perfectly fine in XCode. The part of the Jenkins log that fails is:

```
    CompileXIB Runner/Controllers/UserProfileCoTravelerIndividualViewController.xib
    cd /var/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Runner/workspace
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 5.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /var/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Runner/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/UserProfileCoTravelerIndividualViewController.nib /var/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Runner/workspace/Runner/Controllers/UserProfileCoTravelerIndividualViewController.xib
2014-04-02 12:18:42.884 ibtoold[37071:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-5038/InterfaceBuilder/WidgetIntegration/SimulatedMetrics/IBUISimulatedSizeMetrics.m:33
Details:  (initialTargetRuntime) should not be nil.
Object:   <IBUIFixedSimulatedSizeMetrics: 0x7fb6a480ae70>
Method:   -initWithTargetRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb6a1d05fb0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000104a5dd51 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x0000000104a5d7a9 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000104a5da8f _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000109cb67c0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x0000000109cb7047 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x0000000109cb734a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x0000000109cffc4e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x0000000109cff682 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x0000000109d0033c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x0000000109ca23c8 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 10  0x0000000103af2b0c -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x0000000103af37f2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x0000000103af344f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x0000000103af35f9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x0000000103af2681 __48-[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x0000000103cc3c3a -[IBXMLDecoderAbstractObjectElement enumerateElements:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x0000000103af2607 -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x0000000103af37f2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x0000000103af344f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x0000000103af35f9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x0000000103b705e6 -[IBObjectRecord initWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x0000000103af2b0c -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x0000000103af37f2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x0000000103af344f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x0000000103af35f9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x0000000103af2681 __48-[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26  0x0000000103cc3c3a -[IBXMLDecoderAbstractObjectElement enumerateElements:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27  0x0000000103af2607 -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28  0x0000000103af37f2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29  0x0000000103af344f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30  0x0000000103af35f9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31  0x000000010493ac46 -[DVTMutableOrderedSet initWithCoder:] (in DVTFoundation)
 32  0x0000000103af2b0c -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 33  0x0000000103af37f2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34  0x0000000103af344f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35  0x0000000103af35f9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36  0x0000000103b5f664 -[IBObjectContainer decodeObjectsWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37  0x0000000103b6123d -[IBObjectContainer initWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38  0x0000000103af2b0c -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 39  0x0000000103af37f2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40  0x0000000103af344f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41  0x0000000103af35f9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 42  0x0000000103a9ea98 -[IBDocument decodeDocumentOfType:withCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 43  0x0000000109ca67b7 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 44  0x0000000103a9f5d8 -[IBDocument decodeContentFileWrapper:fileDataType:typeName:decodingStyle:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45  0x0000000103a9fad9 -[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 46  0x0000000109ca69ac (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 47  0x0000000109cab455 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 48  0x0000000109ca6909 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 49  0x00007fff85a87098 -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 50  0x0000000103a97027 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51  0x0000000103ace04f -[IBDocument invokeWithUndoSuppressed:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 52  0x0000000103a96d4f -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53  0x000000010388cb32 (in ibtoold)
 54  0x0000000103887e76 (in ibtoold)
 55  0x000000010388e3ad (in ibtoold)
 56  0x0000000103898b65 (in ibtoold)
 57  0x00000001038990c0 (in ibtoold)
 58  0x0000000103898f90 (in ibtoold)
 59  0x00000001038973e7 (in ibtoold)
 60  0x00000001038987b7 (in ibtoold)
 61  0x0000000103897d6e (in ibtoold)
 62  0x00007fff8152b5fd start (in libdyld.dylib)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
  CompileXIB Runner/Controllers/UserProfileMyAccountMyDetailsViewController.xib
(1 failure)

Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried setting Jenkins to clean before creating a new build. Any ideas why this failure is occurring?

Comment: Does it work straight from CLI or from Xcode?

Comment: Build file is unable to find the .xib full path                                         CompileXIB Runner/Controllers/UserProfileMyAccountMyDetailsViewController.xib --CompileXIB would be  looking should supposed look for Jenkins work space and then code base

Comment: @couchy, Did you found the actual cause of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the xib file imported two times in .xcodeproj

Open .xcodeproj with Sublime Text (for example). And look for your file. If it's there 2 times on import, remove one of the lines (be careful not to remove anything else).

See if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Didn't think that a 4 year old answer would save me, but it did. Simply removing the xib from the project and adding it back again solved the issue for me!